# Scope of X-Men tag and its usage? Is it really suitable for being a franchise tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have an [x-men](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men) tag with the tag wiki

> A film series of superhero films based on the Marvel Comics superhero team of the same name.

Even with having a tag wiki for the universe tag it is still being used inconsistently and doesn't even seem an appropriate name for the franchise tag as the first movie was called X-Men and as per our tagging policy [x-men](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men) should belong to the first film only.

As we decided to tag [movies/films/videos/shows of a given franchise with the associated franchise tag](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/what-to-do-with-the-marvel-cinematic-universe) and following it for [arrowverse](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrowverse), [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) , [dc-extended-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-extended-universe) etc, why not also do it with the X-Men franchise? To do that we sure need a better suited name than [x-men](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men), so that the [x-men](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men) tag can be spared for usage on questions about the X-Men's first film. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see any reason why we can't go with [x-men-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-cinematic-universe). It parallels very nicely with the [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe), and until Fox decides to name it officially, we have no better option. (If/when they do, we can always just rename the tag).

The name is clear and obvious enough that people will recognize it, and both the [X-Men Movies Wikia](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men_Movies_Wiki) and the [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-10005) use the term to describe the film franchise.

SF/F.SE adapted this tag name a while back and so far, it seems to have worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score -3):

Why not [x-men-movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-movies)?

A quick Google of phrases like "X-Men films" and "X-Men Cinematic Universe" shows that unlike the Marvel Cinematic Universe and the DC Extended Universe, 20th Century Fox have not yet given their ever-expanding franchise an actual name.

Until they do, [x-men-movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-movies) seems like the best option. It quickly ensures that people realise that this tag is solely to do with the X-Men films (and their related spin-offs), and a cursory check indicates that there have been no X-Men films made (such as animated films, or previous iterations) that we wouldn't also include under this header.

Comment: But there are two x-men TV series also coming

Comment: Fox has not officially used "X-Men Cinematic Universe" but it's a [recognized term](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men_Movies_Wiki) among [the fans](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-10005)