# Deleted tag: Harry-Potter-Universe / Potterverse

Tags: discussion, tags

In continuation to the topic [What to do with the [marvel-cinematic-universe]?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/what-to-do-with-the-marvel-cinematic-universe)
I added the tag: [harry-potter-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-universe) but this one was deleted.

I think it should be added, and used when needed.

Just like other franchises, Fantastic Beasts are only part of the Harry Potter world, and should be treated the same.

Comment: We don't currently do that for *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings* either, though.

Comment: I believe the generic commonly used name is *Potterverse* over on SF&F and it's not a tag there either

Comment: based on the linked question, we should than. I don't see why someone keeps deleting the tag, if the community decided to use them.

Comment: The community decided nothing about that tag. This your question is gathering a community decision, but noone answered yet.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few issues -

1. While "Marvel Cinematic Universe" is the official term for this collection of Marvel film and television properties, it is not the case that "Harry Potter Universe" is an official term. The more generally accepted term would be "Potterverse" but, even then, my understanding is that it's a fan-created term, not an official one.
2. There's no indication that we need this tag. The reality is, the [harry-potter](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) tag is sort of already serving this purpose so I'm not sure that creating a "HP Universe" tag (regardless of the wording) is necessary. I think the easiest action (which requires no retagging of existing questions) is to slightly broaden this current tag definition to be inclusive of the now-broader collection of films.

Having a question require three tags simply to identify it as a Harry Potter question ([harry-potter-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-universe), [harry-potter](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter), [specific-title](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-title) seems like too much. I feel that [harry-potter](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) is sufficient with the addition of the film's title tag.

Perhaps, sometime in the future, SE will see fit to extend the max length of tags so that the film tags can be [harry-potter-and-the-philosophers-stone](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-and-the-philosophers-stone).

---

Another possibility would be that if we opted for a different wording we could make [harry-potter](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) merge with whatever wording we opted for whether that's [harry-potter-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-universe) or [potterverse](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potterverse) or whatever but I still strongly prefer that we not have both of these tags.

Comment: Neither is "X-Men Cinematic Universe" but that's what *we* went for http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/scope-of-x-men-tag-and-its-usage-is-it-really-suitable-for-being-a-franchise-ta

Comment: @cde that was decided by community consciousness as there was not official name.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how is the [tag:harry-potter] tag used on this site? Is it for all on-topic Potterverse material, or just for the 8 original films? If the latter, then there should certainly be an overarching tag for the whole Potterverse franchise; if the former, then perhaps the tag could be renamed [tag:potterverse] or similar?

Comment: @randal'thor until now, we've only had the 8 films, right?

Comment: @Catija Yes, so my question amounts to "how are Fantastic Beasts questions being tagged here on M&TV?" I guess I could just go and check ...

Comment: @randal'thor That's sort of the entire point of my answer... I'm trying to propose that we use it as the former because there's no reason to have a tag for the original series **and** a tag for all HP content... that means every HP question about the original films would need at least three tags. My understanding is that the only reason we even have a HP tag is because all of the titles are too long with the tag length limits.

Comment: You mean [tag:harry-potter-and-the-philosophers-stone] of course.

Comment: @SQB I doubt she does, since that doesn't seem to be the film's original title.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson It's the British title... "sorcerer" is the American one. One could argue that Philosopher is "more correct"... and that's reflected in the tag here.

Comment: @Catija Then again IMDb calls "sorcerer" the "original title" (and "philosopher" the "world wide (English) title", urgh).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Well, the film is American-based, I suppose? Wikipedia defaults to "philosopher".

Comment: That even inspired me to make [tag:the-sorcerers-stone] synonym. But I think we should go with  sorcerers, as we almost always go for US title and even many country had sorcerers in title.

Comment: @AnkitSharma we don't almost always go for US title, we almost always go for *original* title. That's not necessarily the same.

Comment: @Ankit *Philosopher's Stone* is more canonical, since the original author is British and the film was set, filmed, and produced in Britain.

Comment: @randal'thor The book or its author has no bearing on the matter at all, we're not tagging the book here. Neither is it relevant where the film was set.

Comment: +1. I can't think of many (or any?) questions that would require Potterverse tag on top of Harry-Potter tag. And I'm SFF's resident tag champion and defender :)

Comment: Having said that, I feel compelled to plug my Meta.SE proposal for hierarchical tags, which would solve MOST issues like this, by design: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so. In other words, "Fantastic-Beasts" tag would automatically imply both Harry-Potter and, if it is created, Potterverse tags; so you only need **one**, ever.

Answer (score 3):

I honestly disagree with both the MCU tag and the Potterverse tag, unless the question is specifically asking about those things.  Tags are supposed to be about the SUBJECT of the question, what's being asked about is using tags to identify tags.

Comment: The original plan of these tags was that they should only have been used when more than one property was being discussed... so if you were asking about *Iron Man*, you only use the [tag:iron-man] tag... apparently that's not what the site decided based on the [linked question above](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/what-to-do-with-the-marvel-cinematic-universe), so arguing it here isn't of much use.